# How do i print my result by helper from one view to another view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using my own helper first time have made a simple helper function for my sidebar filter in a shoping cart site,
the helper function is called `helper_helper` my sidebar is actually filtering price and categories i'm sending data to helper function to return my result. Now i have got the result but how do i use it in a `view` which is different from `sidebar view` ?

> Sidebar view

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('helper');
if ($this->input->post()) 
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $search_result = search_sidebar($post);
    //i get result here
    //if(isset($search_result)) print_r($search_result);
} 
?>
<form method="post" id="filters_form">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-shop sidebar-left">
        <div class="widget widget-filter">
            <div class="box-filter category-filter">
                <h2 class="widget-title">Categories</h2>
                <?php 
                    echo sidebar_links('categories',$ul=true); 
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- End Category -->
            <div class="box-filter price-filter">
                <h2 class="widget-title">price</h2>
                <div class="inner-price-filter">
                    <ul>
                        <li><input name="price" class="submit" type="radio" value="< 10" <?php echo set_radio('price' , '< 10')?> /> $ Under-10</li>
                        <li><input name="price" class="submit" type="radio" value="10-20" <?php echo set_radio('price' , '10-20')?> /> $ 10-20</a></li>
                        <li><input name="price" class="submit" type="radio" value="20-40" <?php echo set_radio('price' , '20-40')?> /> $ 20-40</a></li>
                        <li><input name="price" class="submit" type="radio" value="40-50" <?php echo set_radio('price' , '40-50')?> /> $ 40-50</a></li>
                        <li><input name="price" class="submit" type="radio" value="50-80" <?php echo set_radio('price' , '50-80')?> /> $ 50-80</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="range-filter">
                        <label>$</label>
                        <div id="amount"></div>
                        <button class="btn-filter">Filter</button>
                        <div id="slider-range"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="box-filter category-filter">
                <h2 class="widget-title">Brands</h2>
                <?php 
                    echo sidebar_links('brands',$ul=true); 
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- END Brands -->
        </div>
       </div>
       <!-- End Sidebar Shop -->
     </div>
</form>

//script tag start

$('.submit').click(function() {
 // alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
 $('#filters_form').submit();
});

//script tag close
```

> Helper Function in Helper Direcotry

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function search_sidebar($post='')
{
 if ($post) 
 {
    $ci =& get_instance();

    if (isset($post['categories'])) 
    {
        $category = $post['categories'];
        $ci->db->where('product_category', $category);
    }
    if (isset($post['brands'])) 
    {
        $brand = $post['brands'];
        $ci->db->where('product_brand', $brand);
    }
    if (isset($post['price'])) 
    {
        $price = $post['price'];
        $ci->db->where('product_price', $price);
    }

    $query = $ci->db->get('products')->result();

    if (!empty($query)) 
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

> Product View

```
// not getting result in this view
// sidebar view is being called inside it
// print_r($search_result);
```

I'm simply doing `print_r($search_result)` in `Category Page` which is being loaded with `sidebar` view. Shouldn't is just work like that or am i missing something ? 
I have read documentation but they only refer how to create an `anchor()` if we are using helper function ?
Please guide me where do i have to look at regarding this problem thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting data on `print_r($search_result);`

Comment: no i'm not getting this on the third view @HikmatSijapati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot comment due to reputation limit(50) ,I'm posting an answer :)

Did you check the $post values in your helper.. and the returned result array $query..

If it returns values you can simply put them in foreach loop as follows to print results

```
foreach($search_result as $res){
            echo $res->some_field;
}
```

Check If it helps.. or I will assist you to the extent I know in comments

Comment: sorry if i was not clear, there isn't problem on printing at all. I'm getting result in the sidebar view without any hustle

Comment: Then,Where you're not getting the values? I cannot get it

Comment: i have submitted that form through sidebar view, and when i got the result in the sidebar view i want to print the result in the `category` view. Actually the sidebar view is called inside the category view

Comment: and now you can post comment :)

Comment: Oh thanks for the upvote :) So here is what its like

Comment: $this->load->view('sidebar'); inside category view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132290/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-balu-anand).

Answer (score 0):

In your helper function `search_sidebar()`.

If you want to return data in array format :

```
if (!empty($query)) 
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

If you want to return data in object fromat:

```
if (!empty($query)) 
    {
        return $query->object();
    }
```

Then try with    `print_r($search_result);` you will get data as your required format.Hope it will works.

Comment: i'm getting the result from helper function in `sidebar` view but not in the `category` view

Comment: rather than fetching data in view you can fetch data in controller and then send to the view.

Answer (score 0):

it should be placed before the `sidebar view`,

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('helper');
if ($this->input->post()) 
{
  $post = $this->input->post();
  $search_result = search_sidebar($post);
  //i get result here
  //if(isset($search_result)) print_r($search_result);
} 
?>
```

so that i won't run into the scope problem, after catching form i can load the view
`$this->load->view('sidebar');`
and after getting the result i can do the data in the rest of the view.